# One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Tags: custom-errors

I need help with an error that is occurring in my application when I generate or enable Migrations it states the following error,
"
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

ModulosDeAcessoPerfilUsuario: Name: The EntitySet 'ModulosDeAcessoPerfilUsuario' with schema 'dbo' and table 'PerfilUsuario' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer to a unique schema and table.

"

Comment: Please translate your question to english to ensure you get help. Or use http://pt.stackoverflow.com/  Also please, indicate the technologies you are using and maybe some code.

Comment: I need help with an error that is occurring in my application when I generate or enable Migrations it states the following error,

"One or more validation errors Were Detected During model generation:

ModulosDeAcessoPerfilUsuario: Name: The EntitySet 'ModulosDeAcessoPerfilUsuario' with schema 'dbo' and table 'PerfilUsuario' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer to a unique schema and table. "

Comment: This Applications use aspnet.Mvc, during enable Migrations  show error,


        public PerfilUsuario()
        {
            this.Usuarios = new List<Usuario>();
            this.ModulosDeAcesso = new List<ModulosDeAcesso>();
        }
        public int IdPerfilUsuario { get; set; }

        public string NomePerfil { get; set; }

        public bool FlAdminMaster {get; set; }

Comment: public bool FlAtivio { get; set; }

        public DateTime Datacriacao { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Usuario>Usuarios  { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ModulosDeAcesso> ModulosDeAcesso { get; set; }

Comment: You will get better support if you edit the question instead of adding comments. And please use tags to indicate the language is .NET. I can not help with your problem I am Scala developer but if you tag your question sombedoy will help you.